# I need to write a python script which will make a passwordless connection from one server (server1) to another remote server(server2)

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I have successfully created public private keys to make passwordless ssh connection.
I need to make connection with remote server, go to a particular path, and append some input to sample.log file.
Currently I am using os.system("ssh xxx@aaa.vvv.com") and then the steps to append the input to sample.log file. But my script stops only aftwr making connection with using os.system("ssh xxx@aaa.vvv.com").

Comment: When you execute that command, it starts an interactive SSH session. So it's waiting for you to type commands and then logout.

Comment: Use the Paramiko library to automate SSH sessions.

Comment: You may try this if you don't prefer to use a library `os.system("ssh xxx@aaa.vvv.com \"echo 'new line' >> /my/path/sample.log\"")`

Answer (score 0):

Paramiko Module is best suited for it.

I use it personally to make connections and execute comand from one device to another.

You can find more detailed information of paramiko on https://www.paramiko.org

Comment: I can not install any python package. BTW i got the solution, we can use cat script.py | ssh xx.xxx.xxx.xxx python -                                                             In script we can use os.system("ssh xx.xxx.xxx.xxx")